# Option to add edge colouring in Networkx trace using plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, networkx, trace

In the example given in the plotly website:
https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/

Is there any way to add edge colouring (from a list of hex values for example) for each individual edge?

Just like it is given for the nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate the edges that are going to be different colors and plot them separately. When you call `go.Scatter` for each set of edges, just set the color that you want:

```
colors = ['#ff0000', '#0000ff']
edge_traces = []
for edge_set, c in zip(edge_sets, colors):
    edge_x = []
    edge_y = []
    for edge in edge_set:
        x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
        x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
        edge_x.append(x0)
        edge_x.append(x1)
        edge_x.append(None)
        edge_y.append(y0)
        edge_y.append(y1)
        edge_y.append(None)
    
    edge_traces.append(go.Scatter(
        x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
        line=dict(width=0.5, color=c),
        hoverinfo='none',
        mode='lines'))
```

Just make sure you add the new scatter plots when you create the figure

```
fig = go.Figure(data=edge_traces + [node_trace],
    ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of different colored edges:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.cubical_graph()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[0, 1, 2, 3], node_color='y')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=[4, 5, 6, 7], node_color='g')

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 0)], edge_color='y')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=[(4, 6), (6, 5), (5, 7), (7, 4)], edge_color='g')

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Foe more info, see the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_labels_and_colors.html).